# Navigation bar's buttons disappear after resizing the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As the title says I have a resizing problem with the buttons of the navigation bar I created. When the browser's window gets smaller, the buttons flow off the navigation bar. Here is the code:

```
<div id="bar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
       <div class="container">
         <div id="navbar" class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
             <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="Index.php"><img class="brand" src = "img/logo.jpg"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <?php if ($current_page == 'index') { ?>
        <li class="active"> <?php } else { ?>
        <li class="inactive"> <?php } ?>
        <a href="Index.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span> Products<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="BrowseByTitle.php">Browse by Title</a></li>
            <li><a href="BrowseByArtist.php">Browse by Artist</a></li>
            <li><a href="BrowseByGenre.php">Browse by Genre</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Vote now for your favorite albums!</li>
            <li><a href="rateAlbum.php">Ratings</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <?php if ($current_page == 'about') { ?>
        <li class="active"> <?php } else { ?>
        <li class="inactive"> <?php } ?>
        <a href="AboutTheSite.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> About</a></li>

        <?php if ($current_page == 'signin') { ?>
        <li class="active"> <?php } else { ?>
        <li class="inactive"> <?php } ?>

        <?php if ($current_page == 'logout') { ?>
        <li class="active"> <?php } else { ?>
        <li class="inactive"> <?php } ?>

        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) { ?>
                <a href="Logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Logout</a>
         <?php } else { ?> 
        <a href="SignIn.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> Sign In</a>
        <?php } ?>
        </li>

        <?php if ($current_page == 'contact') { ?>
        <li class="active"> <?php } else { ?>
        <li class="inactive"> <?php } ?>
        <a href="Contact.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> Contact</a></li>

        <?php if ($_SESSION['Admin']!='Y') { ?>
        <div id="sb" class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
             <form action="Search.php" method="post" class="navbar-form" role="search" >
             <div class="input-group">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="searchcriteria">
             <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="submit" value="search"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
             </div>
             </div>
            </form>
        </div> 
        <?php } ?>

       <?php if ($_SESSION['Admin']=='Y') { ?>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Admin Panel<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="ArtistMaintenance.php">Manage the artists list</a></li>
            <li><a href="AlbumMaintenance.php">Manage the albums list</a></li>
            <li><a href="UserMaintenance.php">Manage the users list</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
       <?php } ?>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                <?php echo $_SESSION['user'] ?>
                </a>
             </li>
     </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

And here the CSS:

```
    body{    
   background-color:#FF9;
color:black;
   }
   .brand{
width:200px;
height:33px;
text-align:center;
   }
   #bar {
height:50px;
   }
   #sb {
   width:250px;
   }
```

Comment: The bootstrap `navbar` uses javascript for a responsive feel.  When the page gets too small it turns the buttons into a "dropdown" sort of list.  Make sure that you've loaded the bootstrap.js file into the page.  Otherwise, when the screen gets small, it will hide the navbar, but never fire the javascript to turn it into a dropdown.

Comment: I have load it but when the page gets small it drops the buttons outside the bar.